# Haskell Scion project seems to have two different servers

Tags: haskell, emacs, ide

I'm trying to setup Scion for Haskell development in Emacs.
I'm using original version of Scion from here:
https://github.com/nominolo/scion

My GHC is 7.4.2 and I'm under Ubuntu 12.04 / 13.04.

I compiled scion-server and scion-worker by "cabal install scion".
The problem is that I'm getting errors like "Unknown server command: thing-at-point" when trying to run "thing-at-point" command in Emacs.

I looked into source code and found that (looks like) there are two different servers:

1. scion\src-execs\Server.hs. It uses atto-lisp to parse Emacs lisp requests.
2. scion\server\Scion\Server. Looks like the code here uses JSON requests. I can see that this code support cmdThingAtPoint command, but it is not used by Server which is called from Emacs.

Anybody knows working version/fork (with thing-at-point) of Scion for Emacs, when using GHC 7.4.2?

If not - then is it a good idea to try to integrate these two servers? (like converting lisp request to JSON for instance).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.